# Unable to go back to activity after opening url in browser intent android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to load a external url in a webview and it works fine. But for some reason after the page opens in chrome, upon clicking the back button of the phone, I am unable to navigate to the previous activity. What could i be doing wrong ?

```
public class RegisterUsers extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.adduserview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //put your intent here
         webView.destroy();

    }

}
```

Comment: You're not actually loading the URL in a WebView, you're sending an Intent to open up the browser instead. The WebView is redundant.

Comment: The implementation of back button is managed by the Chrome broswer. If you are at the base page then pressing back should close the Chrome and bring your activity to foreground. To test this, simply open the page and click on back button (without navigating inside page).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code i hope this will solve your problem!

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebview.canGoBack()) {
            myWebview.goBack();
            return;
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

If you want to load your webview inside your app just add this code in onCreate

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```